# How to show temperature of all countries in info window inside map in Android?

Tags: android

Currently i am working on a weather application, in which i am getting temperature of all countries and i need to show that temperature in info window inside map. only one info window is showing at a time, but i need to show multiple info window, so how to accomplish it ?

```
    googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter()
    {

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {

            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.infowindow, null);

            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {

            return null;
        }
    });

    Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(23.48225949, 83.24252575))
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));
    marker.showInfoWindow();
```

Comment: I guess you'll have to map every country to one 'location', which could be for instance a latitude-longitude pair or the capital. Then for every such location, you'll have to make a request to get the weather forecast (as I don't see anything in the api to batch requests). Once you have the data, you'll want to somehow visualise this on the map. In which way exactly is impossible to tell from your question. I suggest you do some more research and break up your problem in more specific, concrete questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also make the icon for the markers hold the information you need instead of relying on showing that information throught the info window. 
That can be accomplished by dynamically creating a bitmap for each marker that includes whatever text you want via canvas.

To avoid doing all tha work yourself you could try using the [google maps utility library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering) , see [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/demo/src/com/google/maps/android/utils/demo/CustomMarkerClusteringDemoActivity.java) for an example on how to use a custom marker adapter. It's a bit of extra work, but its a nice library and the clustering is really nice :)

Comment: Thanx for your reply..! only one info window is showing at a time by this code, i need to show multiple info window at a same time, i will try to this library, i think it will help me..